# how to find list of all files in a remote web page using php

Tags: php, list, file

I'm a beginner in PHP and I want to list of all files that is using in a remote webpage and is using in `.js` AND `.css` files using PHP.

For example I want to get list of all files that is using in `http://sitename.com/gallery.html` and I need a list like this:

```
/css/gallery.css (using in gallery.html)
/css/rtl.css (this file imported in gallery.css)
/images/bodybg.png (this file imported in gallery.css)
/images/gallery/image1.jpg (using in gallery.html)
/images/gallery/image2.jpg (using in gallery.html)
...
```

Like [this](http://tools.pingdom.com/fpt/) that in result of test a web page it is listing all files is using in a web page.

Answer (score 0):

The best way in PHP

```html
<?php
$f = file_get_contents('gallery.html');
$_1 = explode('<link', $f);
$_2 = explode('<LINK', $f);
print_r($_1);
echo '<br/><br/>';
print_r($_2);
?>
```

Comment: This way will list `.css` files only but I want to list all files (css, js, image, font, zip, ...)